# View dockerFile associated with tag

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Is the `dockerFile` associated with the a tag for a container viewable on dockerhub ?

Viewing sample containers such as tensorflow https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/ this information is not available ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the Dockerfile is not available, you can always

- use `docker history` and see what commands were used, see the help

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/

- use Dockerfile-from-image to build the Dockerfile from the image, see

https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image

You will not know exactly what was done, as when you see a `ADD` or `COPY` you can not know exactly which file was copied, with what content, but you will get a good idea

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/docker/Dockerfile

I went to repo info, then more details link in description and explored the github project. You might want to check git tags there for dockerfiles more corresponding to actual tags.

Apparently not everybody publishes them on dockerhub.